# Background runs behind button

Tags: html, css

Background behind button should be like block background. Button can change its width.

[image]

[image]

How I can realise this?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: I have no code concerning button, coz I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be done in a lot of ways, here's just my first idea:

Use a mask like this:

[image: Mask]

1. Make sure your background-image covers the whole button
2. Insert two white divs above the background-image: left & right of your button
3. Insert a Mask like the above as the buttons background

Due to the transparent area (indicated by the texture) you are able to display a border-like part of your background image while the rest of it stays invisible, because its overlapped.

I illustrated the result of the instructions above
[image: result]

Comment: but if the button changes its width?

Comment: then just use split the mask into two: positioned absolute (left:0;width:50% + right:0;width:50%) to the parent relative mask container.

Comment: This is quite interesting if it works, can you make a fiddle?